# How to check file exist in system or not using jinja in html page?

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, jinja2

I want to check that my ***dummy.csv*** exist or not in my local system. If it exist then this Check Fraud Status will be displayed otherwise it won't. I don't want to use Javascript. If any solution relating to python ***jinja*** then please help me out.

And one more thing how to `import os` in html page using jinja?

I had tried this:

**layout.html**

```
{% if os.path.exists('./static/userdata/dummy.csv') %}
   <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="{{ url_for('checkfraudstatus') }}">Check Fraud Status</a>
{% endif %}
```

**error**

```
jinja2.exceptions.UndefinedError: 'os' is undefined
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add this in main.py file which contains import os module.

main.py

```
import os

@app.context_processor
def handle_context():
    return dict(os=os)
```

layout.html

```
{% if os.path.exists('./static/userdata/dummy.csv') %}
     <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="{{ url_for('checkfraudstatus') }}">Check Fraud Status</a>
{% endif %}
```

It worked for me. Hope it help to others.

Comment: Doesn't that inherently make templates insecure, since you're making the entire 'os' module accesible to them?

Answer (score 4):

Another way to check for the file existence is to define a custom function for this.

```
from jinja2 import Template
import os


def path_exists(path):
    return os.path.exists(path)


template = Template("""
{% if path_exists('template.html') %} 
    File is found 
{% else %} 
    File not found 
{% endif %}
""")

print(template.render(path_exists=path_exists))
```

Comment: This feels like a better solution since it does not make the whole 'os' module available to templates.